# Looking for maintained Select input JavaScript or jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, drop-down-menu

I am looking for JavaScript or jQuery plugin for nicer rendering of Selectbox input. Requirements: optgroups, multiple, with icons/images (either configurable or easily manually extendable). So far I have found few (i.e. Chosen) but they are not maintained anymore.

Comment: Questions about the recommendation of a tool or a library are off-topic on StackOverflow. Try [SoftwareRecommendation](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) Sister site.